# how can i push code in to jenkins and it will automatically deploy code in to github in it possible?

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

I am new to jenkin's but what i am looking for is as below
       1.How to create project or how to push your code in to jenkin's?
       2.How it will directly push this code into github's branch?
      I have followed some tutorial but nothing is clear.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is not a repository, Jenkins is just a CI tool, basically build server, you cannot "store" codes in Jenkins, but yes, it is able to pull codes from repositories and eg. build it. (or push artifact- war/jar/ whatever to some machine via ssh eg.- look for publish over ssh plugin for this)

Create eg. freestyle project, and then take a look into "Source code management" section, there you can choose git, github, svn, whatever.. Will fill credentials and repo URL, then in "Build" step you will choose what you need to do.

For build check [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Jenkins/article.html#setting-up-a-jenkins-job)

If you really mean how to push the changes back to repository, than I have found [this](http://thingsyoudidntknowaboutjenkins.tumblr.com/post/23596855946/git-plugin-part-3)- its done with git plugin.

I am not sure, but either you didnt understood what the jenkins is for, or you are using not proper name convetions. Hope that helps.

> We found [this solution](http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/configuring-automatic-push-by-successfully) works
>
> It uses `Add post-build action ⇒ Git Publisher`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation I am Learning Jenkins but can i install maven into my Jenkins and maven will connect to git plugin and that will directly push my code to GitHub's branch ?

Comment: Regarding the plugin description it looks like its a simply git command line for the jenkins, so you should to be able do this in it. But I dont have any xp with pushing codes back to git from Jenkins and especially to GitHub. It looks like there is also some [hook option](https://medium.com/@marc_best/trigger-a-jenkins-build-from-a-github-push-b922468ef1ae)

Comment: @xxxvodinikxxx Thanks :) i found the solution

Comment: @user2406 nice to see, If I can ask, put the answer with the steps which you followed and mark it as accepted when possible. To prevent see question like unanswered and for the future if someone will be looking for similar solution. Thanks and good job.

Comment: @xxxvodinikxxx I follow this website http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/configuring-automatic-push-by-successfully Thanks